Man trapped in toilet and rescued by cousin
I am trying to identify a movie I saw many years ago. It has a memorable scene with the male lead being trapped in a public toilet. He is rescued by woman that proves to be his estranged cousin. A cousin that used to be male. There is a running theme of the male lead's spectacles being taken off and breathed upon (ready to be cleaned with a handkerchief)
I have obviously not got anything like the correct name (I thought it was something like Guilio Guilia) as my many searches have been fruitless.
I think the movie is Italian. It was probably made in the late 80s. The male lead was an architect. He moves in with his transgender cousin (pre op).

Can you please edit the Title Question so it is a question? Also, any other details, no matter how minor, may help someone remember or find the movie you are looking for. Approximate year, other characters or settings, was it a Hollywood movie, etc.

I edited the title as best I can - can you provide any of the details that @MeatTrademark suggests?


Belle al bar (1994)

An Italian comedy which charts the friendship-cum-romance between Leo,
  a nuerotic, unhappily married man and Giulia, an amenable
  transvestite, who is later discovered to be his former cousin Giulio.
  (Edited from TCM.com)

You can view clips from the movie here, here and on this page.
Also, some stills from the movie here (scroll down to the bottom for the gallery).
